# Netlify changing the case of my react components?

Tags: reactjs, directory, netlify, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

While trying to debug an issue I was having with deploying a react app to Netlify, I found an odd bug that I think might be ruining my deployment. After getting a 404 error multiple times, I started running through a forum post with ideas on what my issues could be and after getting to the end of it, the last idea was to download the files that Netlify was using to deploy and try running on your local machine. When I went to run the downloaded version I got an error that App.js could not be found. I looked at my files and to my surprise all of my filenames were lowercase. I use uppercase naming for my components and pages and have deployed multiple projects through Netlify with the same naming convention.

I've checked the GitHub repo that I am deploying from and the names are correct there. The only thing I can think of is maybe an error with the git. Ignore after I built the react app in a folder that was deeper than the GitHub repo clone.

edit:
After posting I am realizing that this might not be my issue. The deployer on Netlify would have this same error as my terminal if it couldn't find the app.js file. Instead, I am getting a 404 blank page error from Netlify after a supposedly successful deployment.

My file structure:

[image: Image of my file structure]

Downloaded file structure:

[image: image of downloaded file structure]